# How to get time-stamp to work with mhtml-mode

Tags: html, emacs

I can't get the time-stamp to update.  Error is probably in this code, which I have in my .emacs.el.

```
; Enable time stamps
(setq 
  time-stamp-active t          ; do enable time-stamps
  time-stamp-line-limit -10     ; check last 10 buffer lines for Time-stamp:
  time-stamp-pattern "Last modified:[ \t]+%3a %3b %02H:%02M:%02S %Z %:y by %u</p>"
  time-stamp-format "%04y-%02m-%02d %02H:%02M:%02S (%u)") ; date format
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)
```

I've also tried this in a .dir-locals.el file

```
((mhtml-mode . ((time-stamp-pattern . "-8/<p>Last modified:[ \t]+%3a %3b %02H:%02M:%02S %Z %:y by %u</p>")
                   (time-stamp-time-zone . "UTC"))))
```

Where is the error, or what is missing.  Thanks

P.S. Should have added file at the end contains

```
  <!-- hhmts start -->
  Last Modified: Fri Aug 21 07:37:47 PDT 2020
  Time-stamp: <>
<!-- hhmts end -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not all that I wanted, but with this in .emacs.el

```
; Enable time stamps
(setq 
  time-stamp-active t          ; do enable time-   stamps
  time-stamp-line-limit -10)     ; check last 10 
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)
```

And this near the end of the .html file

```
   Time-stamp: <>
```

I get time-stamp that works.  Just not with the text I would have preferred.